# decipher( s ) python

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

Decipher( S ) will be given a string of English text shifted by some amount. Then, decipher should return, to the best of its ability, the original English string, which will be some rotation (possibly 0) of the input S. This means I have to try each possible decoding and estimate how English they are.

My approach is to use letter frequencies:

```
def letProb( c ):
    """ if c is an alphabetic character,
    we return its monogram probability (for english),
    otherwise we return 1.0 We ignore capitalization.
    Adapted from
    http://www.math.cornell.edu/~mec/2003-2004/cryptography/subs/frequencies.html
    """
    if c == 'e' or c == 'E': return 0.1202
    if c == 't' or c == 'T': return 0.0910
    if c == 'a' or c == 'A': return 0.0812
    if c == 'o' or c == 'O': return 0.0768
    if c == 'i' or c == 'I': return 0.0731
    if c == 'n' or c == 'N': return 0.0695
    if c == 's' or c == 'S': return 0.0628
    if c == 'r' or c == 'R': return 0.0602
    if c == 'h' or c == 'H': return 0.0592
    if c == 'd' or c == 'D': return 0.0432
    if c == 'l' or c == 'L': return 0.0398
    if c == 'u' or c == 'U': return 0.0288
    if c == 'c' or c == 'C': return 0.0271
    if c == 'm' or c == 'M': return 0.0261
    if c == 'f' or c == 'F': return 0.0230
    if c == 'y' or c == 'Y': return 0.0211
    if c == 'w' or c == 'W': return 0.0209
    if c == 'g' or c == 'G': return 0.0203
    if c == 'p' or c == 'P': return 0.0182
    if c == 'b' or c == 'B': return 0.0149
    if c == 'v' or c == 'V': return 0.0111
    if c == 'k' or c == 'K': return 0.0069
    if c == 'x' or c == 'X': return 0.0017
    if c == 'q' or c == 'Q': return 0.0011
    if c == 'j' or c == 'J': return 0.0010
    if c == 'z' or c == 'Z': return 0.0007
    return 1.0
```

Also I use this formula:

```
def list_to_str( L ):
    """ L must be a list of characters; then,
    this returns a single string from them
    """
    if len(L) == 0: return ''
    return L[0] + list_to_str( L[1:] )
```

And this:

```
def rot(c, n):
    """ rot rotates c, a single character forward by n spots in the 
        alphabet
        input: a single character
        input: a non-negative integer n between 0 and 25
        output: c forward by n spots in the alphabet
    """
    if 'a' <= c <= 'z':
        neword = ord(c) +n
        if neword > ord('z'):
                neword = neword - 26
    elif 'A' <= c <= 'Z':
        neword = ord(c) + n 
            if neword > ord('Z'):
                neword = neword - 26
    else:                       
        neword = ord(c) 
    return chr(neword)
```

And finally this:

```
def decipher( S ):
    """
    """
    L = [[rot(c, n) for c in S] for n in range(26)]
    LoL = [[sum(letProb(c)) for letter in encoding] for encoding in L ]
    L = max(LoL)
    return list_to_str(L)
```

The first two formulas are good, but in the final formula there is something wrong, for sure in the sentence:

```
LoL = [[sum(letProb(c)) for letter in encoding] for encoding in L ]
```

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: Use a table lookup for your probabilites and use `lower` to fold the case.

Comment: In the expression `[[sum(letProb(c)) for letter in encoding] for encoding in L ]` the variable `c` is never assigned a value so its final value from the line above is constantly the last character of `S`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to *sum(letProb(c))* where *letProb* returns a Float, and *sum* needs an iterable, a list o a generator, lets say. Try something like this.

```
LoL = [[sum(letProb(c) for letter in encoding)] for encoding in L ]
```

I also think that *c* maybe should be *letter*, but I don't, if you post complete code, *rot* function included, maybe I can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the following useful. You could use some kind of lookup for the letter probabilities. If a dictionary is used, you can use `get` to provide your default probability of `1.0` for non A to Z characters.

Secondly, Python's `string` module has a `make_trans` function that could be used with `translate` to perform your rotations.

```
import string

letter_probs = {
    'e' : 0.1202, 't' : 0.0910, 'a' : 0.0812, 'o' : 0.0768,
    'i' : 0.0731, 'n' : 0.0695, 's' : 0.0628, 'r' : 0.0602,
    'h' : 0.0592, 'd' : 0.0432, 'l' : 0.0398, 'u' : 0.0288,
    'c' : 0.0271, 'm' : 0.0261, 'f' : 0.0230, 'y' : 0.0211,
    'w' : 0.0209, 'g' : 0.0203, 'p' : 0.0182, 'b' : 0.0149,
    'v' : 0.0111, 'k' : 0.0069, 'x' : 0.0017, 'q' : 0.0011,
    'j' : 0.0010, 'z' : 0.0007}

def rotate(text, rotate_by):
    s_from = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase
    s_to = string.ascii_lowercase[rotate_by:] + string.ascii_lowercase[:rotate_by] + \
           string.ascii_uppercase[rotate_by:] + string.ascii_uppercase[:rotate_by]
    cypher_table = string.maketrans(s_from, s_to)
    return text.translate(cypher_table)

def sum_probs(text):
    global letter_probs
    return sum(letter_probs.get(c.lower(), 1.0) for c in text)

def decipher(text):
    probabilities = []
    for r in range(26):
        rotated = rotate(text, r)
        probabilities.append((sum_probs(rotated), rotated, r))
    return sorted(probabilities)

for probability, decoded_text, rotate_value in decipher("Mjqqt Btwqi"):
    print '{:2.2f}  {:2}  "{}"'.format(probability, rotate_value, decoded_text)
```

This would display all possibilities in probability order:

```
1.17  19  "Fcjjm Umpjb"
1.20  16  "Czggj Rjmgy"
1.22   9  "Vszzc Kcfzr"
1.26  20  "Gdkkn Vnqkc"
1.28  13  "Zwddg Ogjdv"
1.29   4  "Qnuux Fxaum"
1.29  15  "Byffi Qilfx"
1.30   8  "Uryyb Jbeyq"
1.31   6  "Spwwz Hzcwo"
1.32   5  "Rovvy Gybvn"
1.32   0  "Mjqqt Btwqi"
1.33  12  "Yvccf Nficu"
1.34   1  "Nkrru Cuxrj"
1.37  23  "Jgnnq Yqtnf"
1.39   7  "Tqxxa Iadxp"
1.40  22  "Ifmmp Xpsme"
1.40   2  "Olssv Dvysk"
1.44  25  "Lipps Asvph"
1.45  17  "Dahhk Sknhz"
1.47  24  "Khoor Zruog"
1.49  11  "Xubbe Mehbt"
1.52   3  "Pmttw Ewztl"
1.56  10  "Wtaad Ldgas"
1.58  21  "Hello World"
1.61  14  "Axeeh Phkew"
1.68  18  "Ebiil Tloia"
```

As you can see, the answer is near the bottom.